# Ramda function for calling an object's method with arguments?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Does Ramda.js have a function that can be used to call a method on an object? Basically something equivalent to this:

```
(methodName, argumentList) => o => o[methodName].apply(o, argumentList);
```

I've looked through the function list a few times and haven't found anything that appears to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use R.invoker with R.apply to get what you want. However, as you can see, it's a bit clunky and not that readable:

```js
const { curry, apply, invoker, length } = R

const fn = curry((methodName, argumentList) =>
  apply(invoker(length(argumentList), methodName))(argumentList)
)

const slice = fn('slice', [1, 4])

const result = slice('abcdefghijklm')

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

With Vanilla JS using spread, the function becomes simpler and more readable:

```js
const fn = (methodName, argumentList) => o => o[methodName](...argumentList)

const slice = fn('slice', [1, 4])

const result = slice('abcdefghijklm')

console.log(result);
```

You can also curry the vanilla function:

```js
const fn = R.curry((methodName, argumentList, o) => o[methodName](...argumentList))

const slice = fn('slice', [1, 4])

const result = slice('abcdefghijklm')

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```